# if a line contains a pattern and is followed by another line with same pattern delete the first line

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

My apologizes... I have brain freeze and can't work through this.
I'm using sed and pattern space, but I keep deleting all occurrences of the lines containing the pattern.

I want to delete only the first line containing the pattern, when followed by another line containing the same pattern.

The list I am using will never have more than two consecutive lines containing the same pattern

The pattern is "Query"

This my data:

```
Query: A ANNUAL SERVICE FEE                                                                          
       SourceField:               EXP-ANNUAL:       SourceTable:               MASTER
Query: A ANNUAL SERVICE FEE                                                                          
Query: A Edie ACTIVE LNS                                                                             
       SourceField:               LOAN-NO:      SourceTable:               MASTER
Query: A Edie ACTIVE LNS                                                                             
       SourceField:               LO:           SourceTable:               MASTER
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
Query: A ANNUAL SERVICE FEE                                                                          
       SourceField:               EXP-ANNUAL:       SourceTable:               MASTER                                                                      
Query: A Edie ACTIVE LNS                                                                             
       SourceField:               LOAN-NO:      SourceTable:               MASTER
Query: A Edie ACTIVE LNS                                                                             
       SourceField:               LO:           SourceTable:               MASTER
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/^Query/{N;/\nQuery/D;}' file
```

On lines which begin with `Query`, append next line to pattern space. If next line begins with `Query`, delete first line.

To avoid printing last line (if last line matches `^Query`):

```
sed -n '/^Query/{N;/\nQuery/D;};p' file
```

Comment: Than you so much! This works very nicely